# Using BPXWUNIX to invoke sftp with a batch file - host not authenticating

Tags: sftp, mainframe, rexx, omvs

Using this BPXWUNIX setup:

```
cmd is set as:  sftp -b /u/lbdyck/tmp/sftp.stdin userid@ftp.host.com
```

x = bpxwunix(cmd,,so.,se.,env.)

With an environment variable of:

```
 DISPLAY=NONE                              
 SSH_ASKPASS=/u/lbdyck/.ssh/sftp.sftpsh
```

And I get this:

```
FOTS1370 Host key verification failed.:                           
FOTS0841 Connection closed:
```

The askpass file is a small shell script that does an echo of the users password since we're unable to exchange keys.

I have confirmed that the askpass file has permissions of 700.

Thoughts/suggestions??

Comment: You write "with **an** environment variable", but you show two of them. Did you assign them to `env.1`, and `env.2`, resp. and have you set `env.0=2`?

Comment: yes - i set env.1, env.2 and env.0

Comment: You don't show how you invoke `bpxwunix`. Can you edit your Q and add the whole REXX, and how you start the REXX, i.e. from TSO session, in a bacth job, from a UNIX shell, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to work - but using bpxbatch does.

```
//SFTP     EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH, 
// PARM=('sh sftp support@ftp.support.com') 
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* 
//STDIN    DD PATH='/u/user/sftp_input.txt' 
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=* 
//STDENV   DD * 
DISPLAY=NONE
SSH_ASKPASS=/u/userid/.ssh/sftp_test.sh
/*
```

Comment: Would you add more details of how `bpxbatch` is called, i.e. the batch JCL, the REXX, other?

Comment: Thanks. I have copied the sample job to the Q. You might want do delete the obsolete comment. Would you mind to add to the Q above how `bpxwunix` was called?